# How to reconstruct a connected Lie group, from a given lattice in it?

Tags: geometric-group-theory

I know that some works of Hillel Furstenberg and George D. Mostow, are in this direction. Can some one hint me towards the process of this reconstruction or send a link of the original papers, please.